# Problems with Simultaneous Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, gaussian-elimination

I have a problem with:

```
2x + 4y = 32
2x - 3y = 11
```

I know that I should add because the signs are different. But if I tried to eliminate the `2x` by adding `2x` and `2x`, I'll get `4x` and not `0`. IT will only work if it is `2x + -2x`. How Do I solve it correctly?

Comment: substract both equations and solve for $y$

Comment: What have you tried? What can you do to one of these to make adding eliminate the x terms?

Comment: @user577215664 But I know that if the signs are different, I must add.. Am I wrong?

Comment: The signs for $x$ are the same here  and $2x-2x=0$

Comment: Oh thanks! ....................

Comment: Multiply the second equation by $-1$ and then add, if you must.